# PHP preg_replace: How to remove the tag with inner tag

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to use preg_replace to remove  tag and it works except for  that contains another element like

```
<span class="img" style="margin-left:20px">
  <img src="/upload/photo/news/357/0/270x140o/688.jpg?q=1" width="250" height="125">
</span>
```

I use this code

```
echo preg_replace('/<span[^>]*>.*?<\/span>/i', '', $txt);
```

which contains text gets removed and text too but not  containing the image. How to modify the code to remove the  with the  too?

Comment: use [nodeValue](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php)

Comment: Regular expressions are _not_ able to reliably process HTML markup. That is one of the first basic things one understands when diving into complexity theory. Use a DOM parser for this job. Using regular expressions will lead you down a path of endless frustration for endless exceptions.